# What's the PowerShell command to add server to the serverpool of RDS

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2016

We have a RDS Serverfarm containing one AD-Server and two RDS-Servers. AD is Server 2012 R2, RDS servers are Server 2016.

When I login to the RDS Servers after a server restart via Teamviewer and open the servermanager to manage connections, I always have to add the servers to the server pool, to see the connections. This is kind of annoying

Is there a PowerShell cmdlet which I can use to set up my serverpool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no PowerShell command that adds servers to Server Manager. Therefore you have to edit ServerList.xml before starting Sever Manager and this can be done with PowerShell.

**1. Close Server Manager**

```
get-process ServerManager | stop-process –force
```

**2. Set path to existing ServerList.xml file**

```
$file = get-item "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\ServerManager\ServerList.xml"
```

**3. Backup ServerList.xml**

```
copy-item –path $file –destination $file-backup –force
```

**4. Get content from ServerList.xml in XML format**

```
$xml = [xml] (get-content $file )
```

**5. Clone an existing managed server element to a new XML element**

```
$newserver = @($xml.ServerList.ServerInfo)[0].clone()
```

**6. Update the new cloned element with new server information**

```
$newserver.name = “servername.domain.com” 
$newserver.lastUpdateTime = “0001-01-01T00:00:00” 
$newserver.status = “2”
```

**7. Append the new cloned element inside the ServerList node**

```
$xml.ServerList.AppendChild($newserver)
```

**8. Save the updated XML elements to ServerList.xml**

```
$xml.Save($file.FullName)
```

**9. Re-launch Server Manager to see the results**

```
start-process –filepath $env:SystemRoot\System32\ServerManager.exe –WindowStyle Maximized
```

Of course, you can run all the commands as a single script or save the adjusted file somewhere and copy it over at start up. That will do the job.

Comment: thx! i'll test this when I have time and come back to you then

Comment: Did it work for you?